NestJS Cron Job causing dependencies like UserRepository to be undefined in Subscriber
I am working with NestJS and TypeORM, and I have implemented a Subscriber to update user ranks based on their total rewards. However, when I use a Cron job to update user data periodically, the repositories (UserRepository, UserRewardRepository) inside the Subscriber constructor are coming as undefined.
Here is the issue:

I have a Cron job running at scheduled intervals that updates the user ranks.
When the Cron job runs, it seems like the repositories are not correctly injected or initialized in the Subscriber.
When the Cron job executes, I am getting undefined for repositories such as UserRepository and UserRewardRepository.

How can I ensure that the dependencies like UserRepository are correctly injected into the Subscriber when using Cron jobs or other background tasks in NestJS?
I am using the @InjectRepository() decorator and @Cron() decorator in my Subscriber.
Example:
@Injectable()
export class UserRewardSubscriber {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private userRepository: Repository<User>,
    @InjectRepository(UserReward) private userRewardRepository: Repository<UserReward>,
  ) {}
  
  @Cron('0 0 * * *') 
  async updateRanks() {
    // Some operations
  }
}


Dependency injection happens at the start of the nest app. To find out if the DI works properly, you can add onModuleInit method to the UserRewardSubscriber (which implements OnModuleInit interface) and make a test call to the repository.
